# Why does JAWS not read this entire sentence?

Tags: jaws-screen-reader

We are adding JAWS screen reader support into our existing web site and running into an issue with how JAWS is reading within IE11 (we are told to use IE11 for testing).  I am using JAWS 2018 Professional.

With the following HTML markup when the JAWS user presses the Down arrow JAWS stops reading after the words "fifteen business" every time.  Pressing Down arrow again it reads the remainder of the sentence.

```html
<p>
Your confirmation request will be completed within 5 business days. Please note year end requests often take longer, please expect a ten to fifteen business day completion time.<br/>
<a href="#faqtop">Back to Top </a>
</p>
```

Being a sighted, new-to-JAWS person myself I am wondering if using the Down arrow is the correct keystroke here.  This was reported to us (I am a developer) by our testing team and they are using the Down arrow.

Is there different markup that I should be using?  Or does JAWS default to reading just a certain amount of text each time?  I also tested with NVDA in IE11 and it also stops reading but after the word "requests".

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The down arrow is for reading the next line. I'm guessing there's some word wrapping going on that makes all but the last few words sit on the same line. Check out [this manual](https://support.freedomscientific.com/Content/Documents/Manuals/JAWS/Keystrokes.pdf) for key commands.